# how to compare current time with many saved time in sqlite database

Tags: android

I have SQlite database in which i have attributes "start time" and "stop time".
Now these field have different time saved in it. I want to use these time and when current time equal to one of the start time it turn phone to silent and when the  relevant stop time reached it becomes unSilent. How i retrieve these time an how  do these comparison?

Comment: what is the format of stored time ? what timezone you are using ?

Comment: format is 13:00 i mean 24hrs format and +5 GMT

Comment: But Brother i have only concern with hours and minutes not specified day i mean this event occurs every day. Basically i am working on android app in which user can save custom volume and vibrate state  and start and stop time from timepickers using this app and when start time match current time relevant volume and vibrate apply and when stop time match it reverts settings

Comment: convert your GMT time to UTC time and then convert compare to time into UTC. once you have the UTC times you can easily compare them.